# How do I prompt a user to connect their google account with my app?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-drive-api

I'm wondering how I'm supposed to prompt a user to login/connect to their google account from my app, so that I can then use their email and password to access their docs/drive. I have an application running on my desktop that connects to a google account's drive, and creates a spreadsheet, and later accesses it for information. Currently I have to hardcode the email and password.

I heard about gaema, but it didn't sound like the right thing. Also I don't know if it makes a difference, but this app is only on my laptop and not running on googles servers. Although it shouldn't... I think.

P.S. I'm new to google app engine and python, and even stackoverflow, so please don't hate my noob question :)

Comment: well, why not just use a classic HTML form to get this kind of input from user?

Answer (score 3):

Asking the users for their usernames and passwords is by no way an acceptable solution, and I'm sure they won't be willing to give it to you. Instead, you need to use some sort of Authorization flow, typically OAuth 2.0.

A complete example application using Google Drive from GAE is explained in [this article](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/python).

Answer (score 2):

So AppEngine makes Google Account-related stuff very easy (surprise surprise :) ). Take a look at the documentation here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/overview. This explains the Users service where you can request that a user log in with their Google credentials. For example (straight from the docs):

```
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import webapp

class MyHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            greeting = ("Welcome, %s! (<a href=\"%s\">sign out</a>)" %
                        (user.nickname(), users.create_logout_url("/")))
        else:
            greeting = ("<a href=\"%s\">Sign in or register</a>." %
                        users.create_login_url("/"))

        self.response.out.write("<html><body>%s</body></html>" % greeting)
```

This checks to see if a user is logged in with their Google account and if not presents them with a login URL. The parts that do the 'magic' are `users.create_logout_url('/')` and `users.create_login_url('/')` methods. They create a link to a special URL where a user can log in (without you having to do any additional formatting/coding). They are then redirected back to your site ('/' sends them to your main page, but you can change however). Hope this helps!

**EDIT**:
As @Wooble points out, this will not grant your application access to the user data - it will simply provide you with some basic information about the user per what is available through the Users service. In order to allow your app to access Google Drive data, the link provided by @SebastianKreft shows a sample application that does the authentication. Additional general information about using OAuth with Drive can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/about-auth). In short, a user needs to grant permission to your app to allow it to access their data, and it does this via an OAuth token (see the documentation for a much better explanation than I can give).

Comment: This logs the user in to your application, assuming you use the users API for anything; it doesn't let you access their Docs/Drive accounts.

Comment: @Wooble Great point - missed the part in the question where he actually needed to do something with their data :) Amending now.